# Concept of Sampradaya

Tags: scripture, tradition, sects, sampradaya

What is the concept of 'Sampradaya' in Hinduism and how does any particular tradition develop into a Sampradaya? And How many divisions and sub-divisions of Sampradayas are there?

Comment: Check the questions in this site that are tagged with "sects" like this one - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/34331/4732